# How to make my buttons not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is make those buttons with class `btnd` that are not disable not clickable to the users.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/44/

Comment: What do you mean by “not clickable”? As is, clicking on any of the buttons does nothing.

Comment: If the middle button in your fiddle isn't what you want, I have no idea what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want the clicking to cause nothing you could use...

```
$('.btnd:not(disabled)').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have no idea if this would cause what you want thought as it's not at all clear what you actually are looking for and more importantly why.

Comment: this is what im looking for :D

Comment: Glad to help although if you explained your reasoning for wanting that sort of function then you'd probably end up being given a better way of performing the whole task.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons already do not do anything since there is no event attached. To give the front-end visual feedback I would suggest changing the cursor to the default.

```
.btnd {
     cursor: default;
}
```